# How to enable unison to login with ssh from systemd service unit?

Tags: ssh, systemd, unison

I have a pdf-sync.path file for systemd runnin in user-space (`systemctl --user enable pdf-sync.path`). Whenever there is a change in the folder that I defined in the path file I want to synchronize that folder with a folder on a remote server via ssh. Thus I created the pdf-sync.service file providing these informations:

```
[Unit]
Description=PDF Sync
```

Problem is that unison does not seem to find my private key in ~/.ssh

```
[Service]Aug 27 15:51:07 sputnik3arch env[28873]: ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/lib/ssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Aug 27 15:51:07 sputnik3arch env[28873]: Permission denied, please try again.
Aug 27 15:51:07 sputnik3arch env[28873]: ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/lib/ssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Aug 27 15:51:07 sputnik3arch env[28873]: Permission denied, please try again.
Aug 27 15:51:07 sputnik3arch env[28873]: ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/lib/ssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Aug 27 15:51:07 sputnik3arch env[28873]: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Aug 27 15:51:07 sputnik3arch env[28873]: Fatal error: Lost connection with the server

ExecStart=/usr/bin/unison pdf_mobile_sync
```

How will I enable unison to login via ssh from the systemd unit?

Comment: do you run the service with specific user (yourself?) or with default as a root? Is the key in your home directory or home directory of `root` user?

Comment: well, in my understanding every service that is enabled with the --user flag runs as this user (other services that I started this way do that too). Yes, the key is in my home folder that means the folder of the owner of the service and process.